(Re)-use Identity-Aware Proxy between browser and backend
I have an SPA served through my App Engines default service by defining a simple yaml/python based static file server.
runtime: python311
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

Next to this, I have a nodejs server deployed as a sub service named backend to access a PostgresDB and provide some data.
runtime: nodejs20
service: backend

This works fine so far, not sure though if this is the intended way since I am not using the "backend-services" feature gcloud provides.
Now I enabled IAP for the Project. I can turn it on at App Engine Level, so it affects my backend as well.

This breaks my app. I get CORS errors in the frontend for my backend calls due to the preflight endpoint not being handled properly.

XHROPTIONS https://backend-dot-foobar.ey.r.appspot.com     CORS Preflight Did Not Succeed

How do I use the current authenticated session (which works flawlessly for the frontend) to verify the "browsers" identity during my backend calls? Do I have to implement additional logic somewhere? and if so what kind of authentication is recommended?
Can I use the current session and kind of forward it to the backend request using gcloud features?
Right now I turned it off giving "allUsers" the "IAP-secured Web App User" role, but I would love to have some proper authentication with a view clicks, to be honest.

Is your requirement - you want anybody to be able to access the front end but the backend should only be accessed via the front end i.e. by someone who is coming through the front end?

@NoCommandLine I thought so. Does that make sense or is it common to have backends public and just make sure no bad requests are coming in? Maybe I just have some wrong expectations...

It makes sense. See my response here and here
